# What are the future European Union roaming fees/pricing charges?

Tags: international-travel, eu, data-plans, price, roaming

Since the legislation abolishing roaming charges was itself abolished, what milestones in pricing can we expect and when?

Please no discussions, arguments for national SIM plans and packages.

**Update:**

- timetable of EU Roaming Regulations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations#Common_limits (Thanks Calchas)

Comment: Here is a reasonable summary of what is presently agreed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations#Common_limits

Comment: You don't want discussions (which is correct, SE is not a discussion forum), no arguments (which is wrong, any answer would need to include arguments because since what you are asking hasn't actually happened yet, there is no proof upon which to base your opinion). This cannot be answered, as it has not yet happened and there is no law upon which to base an answer. _Any answer_, including the wiki page, can be opposed, and so there can be no one right answer.

Comment: @CGCampbell This was referring to national SIM packages. They are great but a different league IMHO, and should stand alone as a different topic.

Answer (score 11):

It's not clear. As far as I know, nothing has been ruled out or abolished, it's just that announced dates for vote/approval for new measures slip and nothing has happened yet. There were no further mandatory price cuts planned in the current regulation after the ones that took place last year and therefore no strict timeline. But the idea is still in the air.

The last proposal I heard about (early 2015) would introduce a limited yearly amount of free MB/minutes/text while still allowing operators to charge (lower) fees after that, with a tentative implementation date of 2016 (see [1](https://eu2015.lv/news/media-releases/776-roaming-and-open-internet-council-ready-for-talks-with-ep) and [2](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2015/03/150304-roaming-and-open-internet-council-ready-for-talks-with-ep/)). And there is still vague talk of “phasing out roaming fees” but that would be postponed until after 2018.

Until now, it's the Council that was most reluctant so they won't push for better conditions/speedy implementation but hopefully the other institutions will not block its proposal from becoming the law and that would be the main milestone we can expect. However none of this has been formally approved so that's purely guesswork on my part.

Additionally, the [current regulation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32012R0531) has a built-in review and expiration mechanism. So if nothing happens, the current retail price cap would only extend until the end of June 2017 and then expire. Prices would then become unregulated again (the wholesale cap would last a few more years).

I assume that if prices don't go down by themselves, the EU would at least extend the current price caps into the future, even if the different institutions can't find an agreement to introduce some form of mandatory free roaming. But, as of June 2015, nothing has been decided and those are the only rules in place.

Comment: Do you have any links/references to that last proposal you mention? I'm just curious.

Comment: @JoErNanO I added two references and corrected a mistake in my answer.

Comment: Will there still be continuously price-cuts of the maximum fees, regardless of the ongoing discussions?

Comment: @LoSauer No, that's what I mean by “no approved changes”. In fact, current regulations have a built-in expiration date so even if they don't agree on something better in time, they need to at least formally extend them for a few more years for the current rules to stay in place. Right now, if nothing at all happens, the cap would eventually expire and retail charges would become unregulated again.

Comment: @LoSauer I have edited the answer to clarify this and add a few details.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for clarifying. That would mean there is date upon which certain parties should meet to not piss of a huge constituency. I am positively optimistic.